# Multidimensional Associative Arrays in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative

is there in VB.NET something like this in php?:

```
$var["a1"]['name']="Mike";
$var["a1"]['nick']="MMM";
```

I tried hashtables, dictionary, lists and arrays in .net, all I could get is a simple key=>value array
Is there a simple solution if not, is there a class or something for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always create a structure and place that into a dictionary.

Something like this:

```
Private Structure Person
  Public Name as String
  Public Nick as String
End Structure
```

Then your dictionary like this:

```
  Dim myDictionary as Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Person)
```

Comment: @Meta Structures are a lot more light-weight so if you don't need all the OO stuff a Class provides you're usually better off with a Structure.

Comment: As I understand it, structures are only light-weight if they hold only value types (other structures). This is because value types can be stored on the stack, and avoid the small performance hit of looking up a reference to an object on the heap. String is a class, stored on the heap, so a structure holding two strings is no more light-weight than a class holding two strings.

Comment: @Joel  Yes.  That is the case.  However classes also support inheritence and polymorphism whereas structures do not.  That was the overhead to which I was referring earlier.  Also, keep in mind, if you're performing a large number of operations then a Structure will still be preferable as it sits on the stack (even if the strings/objects within it are still on the heap).